# Problem in Eclipse 3.5 and ubuntu 9.10

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-crash

Someone knows why eclipse close when i click any button. This is because when i try to do something, update eclipse or whatever, eclipse close and it gives me this log...

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc329864f7a, pid=9392, tid=140476827293968
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpango-1.0.so.0+0x24f7a]  pango_layout_new+0x2a
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I think it is something about java, anyone has any solution?¿

Thanks

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/460104

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the discussion ki0 linked to, you can get around the problem in eclipse 3.5.1 by replacing the org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.*.jar from your eclipse/plugins directory with the one at http://launchpadlibrarian.net/36500083/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.1.v3555a.jar.

I already had the 3.5.2 version installed, so that didn't help me, but the discussion on the linked eclipse bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291128 prompted me to download the latest 3.5.x eclipse version for the fix. That Amazon Web Services mirror is nice and fast. =)